# linux script - find java process and restart it if it is more than 80% Mem High

Tags: linux, centos, bash, scripting, java

I want to put in crontab a shell script that will monitor the java process and if it's the memory is more than 80% then I want to restart it.
can any one help?
Thanks!!
Elad.

Comment: More than 80% of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perfect use case for monit. 
http://mmonit.com/

Example Config

`check process foo with pidfile "/var/run/foo"

  start program = "/bin/foo -c foo.conf"

  stop program = "/bin/kill -KILL`cat /var/run/foo.pid`"

if totalmem is greater than X.0 MB for 5 cycles then restart`

The reason you want monit rather than a script is that it can email you, provide logs, and honestly a lot more, but I'll leave the research up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the Java process has an initscript and a PID file, and you want to restart it when it uses more than 1G of RSS memory:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
RAM=`ps -o rss --no-headers -p $(cat /var/run/myservice.pid) || true`
if [ "$RAM" ]; then
    # It's not running
    service myservice start
elif [ "$RAM" -gt 1048576 ]; then
    # It's using too much memory
    service myservice restart
fi
```